# Angular 16 Auth Guard Gives Null Injector error when a service with "httpclient" is injected

Tags: angular, angular-routing, auth-guard, angular-standalone-components

Im trying to create an auth guard for my app.
I have a auth service which has multpile functions and "isAuthenticated" is one of those.
When I inject it into auth guard and try to run it I get below error.
The httpclient works well when no gaurd is used.
What I'm I missing?
Also Canactivate is deprecated hence using CanActivateFn

[REPO](https://github.com/msanthoshofficial/e-commerce/tree/main/frontend/e-commerce)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzDUz.png)

## auth.guard.ts

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivateFn, Router, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth/auth.service';

export const AuthGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
  const authService = inject(AuthService)
  return authService.isAuthenticated()
};
```

## auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  readonly api_url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    ......
  }

  register(email: string, password: string) {
    ......
  }

  authCheck() {
    ......
  }

  isAuthenticated(): any {
    // this.authCheck().subscribe((data:any)=>{return data.message == "Authenticated"})
    return true;
  }
}
```

## main.ts

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

## app.config.ts

```
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter,withHashLocation } from '@angular/router';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


import { routes } from './app.routes';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [ provideAnimations(),provideRouter(routes, withHashLocation())]
};
```

## app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { PrimeNGConfig } from 'primeng/api';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';
import { HeaderComponent } from './core/header/header.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterOutlet,
    ButtonModule,
    HeaderComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'e-commerce';
  constructor(private primengConfig: PrimeNGConfig) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.primengConfig.ripple = true;
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

I have tried injecting the httpclient in auth service still no luck.

Comment: Have you imported HttpClientModule in AppModule?

Comment: @derstauner I'm not using modules here. I have imported HttpClientModule in app.component.ts since I'm using standalone components.

Comment: Could you please add your `main.ts` file?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi` updated the question with the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `provideHttpClient()` in the `providers` list of `bootstrapApplication`.

Comment: It Worked! Thanks. I don't know why Angular didn't complain about this until I used it in auth guard.

Comment: You we're not using the HttpClient before !